# MVC 3 Model property is not being set in partial view called by html.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, model, partial-views

I have an issue with my app, ill try explain by example, I have a form, this form exist of several textboxes and dropdown lists. For reusability I merged 3 drop down lists into a partial view, this partial view i load with @Html.Action, this works ok, when i start the form i see everything appears as it should be, although I dont know why but those required drop down lists directly are shown with red start and said it is required fields.

But when i fill everything in, and i select the values from the drop down lists, and i click on OK, the values from drop down lists are NULL.

I think it will be more comprehendable with a code example:

Main model:

```
public class FormModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    //This is what i'm talking about, that is not being set, the location
    public Location Location { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is the location class, which is then passed to the partial view and normally i think should be set, it looks like this:

```
public class Location
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    public string RegionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string CityId { get; set; }
  }
```

Now we have a partial view for the location:

```
@model TestWebsite.Models.Location
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.Countries, "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId)
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Region -->
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegionId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegionId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegionId)
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- City -->
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CityId)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then we call this partial view in the forms like this:

```
@Html.Action("LocationGroup", "Account", Model.Location)
```

And finally in the controller:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult LocationGroup(Location model)
    {
        model.Countries = GetCountries();
        return PartialView("_LocationView", model);
    }
```

I know it is a lot of code, but i hope you could help me ...

Comment: **But when i fill everything in, and i select the values from the drop down lists, and i click on OK, the values from drop down lists are NULL.** Did you try submitting the forms with `JQuery/JSON` or did you try to set the the form contents by wrapping `Ajax.Begin` ?

Comment: Could you check the names of the properties that are sent to the server (via Firebug, for example) I bet that the names corresponding to your partial view doesnt fit the model in the name form. So mvc cannot to the binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use Editor Templates:

```
@model TestWebsite.Models.FormModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Location)
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
}
```

and add the partial inside `~/Views/[ControllerName]/EditorTemplates/Location.cshtml` or `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Location.cshtml`

code of template:

```
@model TestWebsite.Models.Location
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.Countries, "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId)
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Region -->
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegionId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegionId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegionId)
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- City -->
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CityId)
    </td>
</tr>
```

But if you prefer to have partial in some location (not follow conventions) you could specify the location:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Location, "~/Views/SpecifyLocation/_Location.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Xordal, EditorTemplates are the way to go. Incredibly useful stuff. One thing I noticed the lack of a SelectList. I may be missing something here, but have you tried the following?:

```
 <td class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryId)
</td>
<td class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryId" , "CountryName", null))
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId)
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know about that :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12667845/1643075 But isn't problem of question

Answer (score 0):

Try `Html.RenderPartial` instead of `Html.Action`

Comment: yes, it would work better i think, but i would rather prefer use Action, i read that this way is better, as i need to populate those ddls from database, i will not need to do it twice ...